# create a method for all objects, js vanilla?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, children

I want to create a method that can be called from any object.

I could e.g. create the following method:

```
document.el=function(e){return this.getElementById(e);}
```

Now i could call:

```
document.el("myDiv") //returns <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

but I would like to make the method available from all objects, so I could call:

```
document.body.el("myDiv") //returns document.body.el is not a function
```

Can I make it available from all child elements of document? Maybe through a recursive loop?
Essentially what I'm looking for is something like:

```
*.el=function(e)...
```

Comment: maybe you're looking for Object prototype? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Answer (score 2):

Although [you probably shouldn't be extending the DOM,](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) you could do it by adding a method to the prototype of `HTMLElement`, for example:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.el = function (id)  {
  return this.getElementById(id);
};
```

```html
<div id='div-id'><p id='p-id'>Hello</p></div>
```

```
document.getElementById('div-id').el('p-id').innerText; // `Hello`
```

Comment: This didn't work, but yeah, it's probably not a good idea. I thought it might clean up some syntax for a few functions, but it seems to be quite dangerous(!) Thank you for your help though!